# Binary representation recursion Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

Input: two natural numbers n,k
Output: digit at the 2^k digit of the binary representation of n

My idea was that:

```
Stelle :: Int -> Int 
Stelle n k
```

But now I have the problem that I have no idea how to deal with it. It has something to do with recursion and div/mod but I dont what the start of the recursion is. Can somebody help me please! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The signature should be:

```
stelle :: Int -> Int -> Int 
stelle n k = …
```

as for the base case: when `k = 0`, then you can return `n` modulo two, for the recursive case, you divide `n` by two and subtract one from `k`, so:

```
stelle :: Int -> Int -> Int 
stelle n 0 = …
stelle n k = …
```

where I leave implementing the `…` parts as an exercise.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. That mean, stelle n 0 = mod n 2

Comment: How do you come up with "divide n by two and subtract one from k"?

Comment: @xx33xx44: you make a recursive call where you pass `n` divided by two and `k` minus one instead of `n` and `k`.

Comment: Ah okay if I write stelle n k = (n:2) (k-1) it is wrong, right?

Comment: @xx33xx44: you use `div` to divide, not `:`, and you need to make a recursive call to `stelle`.

Comment: Okay, that mean: stelle n k-1 = div n 2

Comment: Sorry I´m really not super stupid, but I didn´t work

Comment: You need to make an extra call to `stelle`, so `stelle n k = stelle (...) (...)` with `...` to fill in.

Comment: Ah, thanks now I wirte stelle n k = stelle (div n 2) (k-1)